# How to make VS2010/ReSharper remember that I've closed my "Unit Test Sessions"?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, resharper-6.0

I've closed my "Unit Test Sessions" pane in VS2010, but it appears again each time I restart VS.

How can I make VS remember that I've closed this pane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the following option in ReSharper:

`Options > Tools > Unit Testing > Save and restore Unit Test Sessions`